# Do I need to add Boolean variables before or to the synchronized calls to endDay() and beginDay()?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, java-threads

The overall goal is to add 0.00015 daily interest to each account (rounded to the nearest cent) per day after the Tth transaction is completed. Once the Tth transaction is called, no other worker thread (from worker.java) can be called until the beginning of the next day and the banker thread from (banker.java) must be woken up. As far as I can tell the synchronization of the Tth thread works correctly and correctly calls the wakeUpBank() method to wake up the banker thread.

I am trying to use condition variables to synchronize the calls to beginDay() and endDay() using Objects endDayCondition and beginDayCondition as lock objects. Do I need to make Boolean variables and use them in if statements before the use of the synchronized keyword and then change the value of the variables within endDay() or beginDay() in order to make sure that endDay() is called before beginDay() can be called?

So far I have tried not synchronizing them and synchronizing them with "this.data" variable which is a reference to the layer1.java object. When not synchronized they return the correct value (0.0074999) of interest per day to all accounts (in this case 50)  but only end up adding one penny worth of interest to the total of all accounts. When using "this.data" I get different amounts for interest added per day all above $1 and up to $1000 and the total interest added to all accounts is usually more (close to double) than the interest added per day. So far I have not called the program on more than one day. Also to note that the interest per day, when printed to the console is usually printed about halfway before all the threads finish which is why I believe there is an issue with my synchronization and condition variables (or lack of) of beginDay() and endDay().

Here is the run() method from banker.java:

```
public void run()
    {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (this.bank.getBankThreadWait() == false) {
                try {
                    this.bank.wait(); // Bank thread waits for a signal
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
            // The bank's work goes here
            synchronized (endDayCondition) {
                this.bank.endDay();
                endDayCondition.notify(); // Signal the end of endDay
            }

            synchronized (beginDayCondition) {
                this.bank.beginDay();
                beginDayCondition.notify(); // Signal the start of beginDay
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the endDay() and beginDay() methods in layer1.java:

```
void endDay() //called by Banker for assignment, not needed for lab
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.data.length(); i++) {
            double tempValue = this.data.getValue(i);
            this.data.setValue(i, this.data.getValue(i) + 0.00015);
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
            double newValue = Double.parseDouble(df.format(this.data.getValue(i)));
            double tempInterest = newValue - tempValue;
            runningInterest = runningInterest + tempInterest;
        }
        System.out.println("Interest added for the day: $" + runningInterest);
        
    }

    void beginDay() //called by Banker for assignment, not needed for lab
    {
        this.data.setCount(0);
    }
```